# JSON Number/Text Parsing Returns Some Peculiar Results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

```
var thetempaddr0 = '<?php echo home_url(); ?>';
JQuery.ajax({
    url: thetempaddr0,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success : function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, element) {
            jQuery("span#myshoppingcart-news-span").append(jQuery('<div>', {
                text: element[0]
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

The line of console.log(data) prints out  ' Object {201: "11", 209: "22"} ' on console.

Nonetheless, inside tag "span#myshoppingcart-news-span", the browser source prints out:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

But I need `<div>11</div>` and `<div>22</div>`, not `<div>1</div> and <div>2</div>`
What's wrong with my ajax code?

Comment: Its this text: element[0] - just do text: element

Answer (score 4):

Note the correlation:

```
            jQuery.each(data, function(index, element) {
                                         |    | 
                                         |    | 
                               Object {201: "11", 209: "22"}
```

`element` is already the string value inside your object. `element[0]` is simply the first character of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [0] for element:

```
var thetempaddr0 = '<?php echo home_url(); ?>';
JQuery.ajax({
    url: thetempaddr0,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success : function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, element) {
            jQuery("span#myshoppingcart-news-span").append(jQuery('<div>', {
                text: element // Remove: [0]
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

[0] in element is an index for the string.
eg.:

```
var element = "987";

element[0] // 9
element[1] // 8
element[2] // 7
```